# how to install netis WF2123 USB WiFi on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS x64?

Tags: 16.04, wireless, usb

I can not use the "netis Wf2123" adapter (http://www.netis-systems.com/Suppory/de_details/id/1/de/89.html).

My Operating System:

```
Cat / etc / lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID = Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE = 16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME = xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION = "Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"

Uname -a
Linux KB4051 4.4.0-79-generic # 100-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 17 19:58:14 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU / Linux
```

The driver to the device downloaded from the manufacturer's website "netis WF2123 Driver for Linux, 2017-02-21"

At compilation I receive the following message:

```
Root @ KB4051: /tmp/drv.wlan.canon/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042# make
Make ARCH = x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE = -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-79-generic/build M = / tmp / drv.wlan.canon / rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042 modules
Make [1]: entering the directory "/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-79-generic"
  CC [M] /tmp/drv.wlan.canon/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042/core/rtw_cmd.o
  CC [M] /tmp/drv.wlan.canon/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042/core/rtw_security.o
  CC [M] /tmp/drv.wlan.canon/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042/core/rtw_debug.o
/tmp/drv.wlan.canon/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042/core/rtw_debug.c: In function 'dump_drv_version':
/tmp/drv.wlan.canon/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042/core/rtw_debug.c:71:64: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror = date-time]
  DBG_871X_SEL_NL (sel, "build time:% s% s \ n", __DATE__, __TIME__);
                                                                ^
/tmp/drv.wlan.canon/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042/core/rtw_debug.c:71:64: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror = date-time]
/tmp/drv.wlan.canon/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042/core/rtw_debug.c:71:64: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror = date-time]
/tmp/drv.wlan.canon/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042/core/rtw_debug.c:71:64: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror = date-time]
/tmp/drv.wlan.canon/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042/core/rtw_debug.c:71:64: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror = date-time]
/tmp/drv.wlan.canon/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042/core/rtw_debug.c:71:64: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror = date-time]
Cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
Scripts / Makefile.build: 258: runtime recipe error for the target "/tmp/drv.wlan.canon/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042/core/rtw_debug.o"
Make [2]: *** [/tmp/drv.wlan.canon/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042/core/rtw_debug.o] Error 1
Makefile: 1420: failed to execute the recipe for the target "_module_ / tmp / drv.wlan.canon / rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042"
Make [1]: *** [_module_ / tmp / drv.wlan.canon / rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042] Error 2
Make [1]: exit the directory "/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-79-generic"
Makefile: 1686: failed to execute the recipe for the purpose of the "modules"
Make: *** [modules] Error 2
Root @ KB4051: /tmp/drv.wlan.canon/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.4.1_17696.20160509_BTCOEX20160412-0042#
```

lsusb

---

Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0bda:0811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

---

**how to fix ?**

*I am a beginner, when replying, please provide more details.*

Answer (score 0):

This driver needs to be patched. I have a rtl8192EU in my PPA with a patch, but it does not have your device. I can't add it now.

You can fix it yourself.

Open `Makefile` in the driver directory and add there

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wno-date-time
```

after the existing `EXTRA_CFLAGS` lines. This will sort out the build problem.